# Outlook Prompting for password from Exchange server in domain environment

Tags: exchange-2007, outlook, windows-authentication

We are running exchange 2007 in a domain environment.  We have mostly outlook 2003 clients, but in process of upgrading to outlook 07 over the next couple of weeks.

Some users (both 03 & 07) are constantly getting prompted to enter their credentials.  The 07 client I was working on this morning states "needs password" in the bottom right corner.

It is also speratic, as it will work fine most days but not some other days.  The user I was working with this morning, has been working fine. Now it just started up today.

I have been googling this, and have found lot's of information, but nothing that has helped yet.  A lot of the information out there is for outlook users using a external email account.

Being they already logged into the domain, these users should not be prompted for their credentials.

Any advice out there?

Comment: Are you sure that they are logged into the domain?  Does the problem recur after logging in and logging out?

Comment: I just started having this today as well. Did you find a solution?

Comment: +1 this is one of the most annoying problems I see on a daily basis! Some machines just randomly have this for no reason and after Googling and trying out so many solutions, I just don't know what causes it on some machines.

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if the clients are configured to use Outlook Anywhere

> Email accounts > Change > More settings... > Connection

If they're connection via Outlook Anywhere it will always ask for credentials. You can run a `netstat -`n to see if you have any 443 connections to your CAS server as well.

Comment: Thanks @Chirs Hupman - I had the same issue and turning off outlook anywhere I'm no longer locked out of Outlook... however the password prompt dialog still constantly pops up but at least I can read my mail now! (I just move the password dialog out of the way.

Comment: Or ctrl+right-click the Outlook tray icon and select Connection status - it will show HTTPS for Outlook Anywhere and TCP/IP for direct connection.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this exact same issue for two of my clients. It happened after updating the certificate to a signed one. Doing the following has always resolved this.

1. Install the latest Service Pack of Exchange.
2. Next, in the Exchange Management shell, take note of the following and document it (in case you need to revert the info).

`Get-OabVirtualDirectory|fl`

`Get-WebServicesVirtualDirectory|fl`

Specifically make note of the `InternalUrl`. You'll want to change the `InternalUrl` for both the `OabVirtualDirectory` and `WebServicesVirtualDirectory` with the following commands. You'll want to change where it says **servername** to the name of your server.

```
Set-OABVirtualDirectory -Identity "Servername\OAB (SBS Web Applications)" " -InternalUrl https://servername.domain.local/oab

Set-WebServicesVirtualDirectory -Identity "Servername\EWS (SBS Web Applications)" -InternalUrl https://servername.domain.local/ews/exchange.asmx
```

Answer (score 0):

What does your authentication look like in IIS? If it's set to anything other than Integrated Auth, you could see this. Also, are your Autodiscover services configured correctly? How about a certificate, do you have a signed or self-signed one? If I remember correctly, 2003 clients aren't affected by Autodiscover the same way 2007 clients are though.

When you say constantly, does that mean entering creds more than once after opening Outlook, or once per session?

Have you rebooted the Exchange server?

Comment: That is something I was looking into, but I haven't been able to find in IIS where I set the integrated Auth.  I was also looking into the autodiscover.

Comment: Go to the site properties that Exchange is under and click on the Directory Security tab. Then click Edit under Authentication and access control. Once there, at the bottom you will see the auth method that the site is using.